# Why is Lua only printing the first word in a string?

Tags: string, printing, lua

I'm making a simple program in Lua that sends a message, however for some reason it only prints the first word in the string (for example: 'Hello World!' prints 'Hello')
This is all the code so far:

```
local msg = (...)
print('Message:',msg)
```

I am very new to Lua, I started about a week ago.

Answer (score 4):

When you call a program like

```
lua some_program.lua foo bar baz
```

then the program will have three separate string arguments:

```lua
local a, b, c = ...
print(a) -- foo
print(b) -- bar
print(c) -- baz
```

So in your case, the `(...)` only gives you the first argument.

There's two ways to go about this:

You can make sure the program gets called with only one long string argument by quoting it:

```sh
lua some_program.lua "foo bar baz"
```

or you can take all the arguments you get through `...` and concatenate them. This is easily done using `table.concat`:

```lua
local msg = table.concat({...}, " ")
print("Message:", msg)
```